# Parent class referencing child variable

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have several similar classes inheriting from the same Base-Class/Interface (Base class 1), and they share a couple similar functions, but then also have their own distinct functions. They all also have their own member variables of different classes, and each of those inherits from the same Base-Class/Interface (Base class 2). Is it possible to define a variable in Base class 1, of type Base class 2, then in the actual implementation of classes using Base class 1, have the variable of type Base class 2 be its proper type. Kinda hard to explain, so simplified example below.

```
//Base-Class 1
class Shape
{
    public Shape() {}
    ShapeExtra m_var;

    //The common functions
    public GetVar(){ return m_var; }
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle() { m_var = new CircleExtra(); }

    public void CircleFunc()
    {
        m_var.CircleExtraFunc();
    }
}
class Triangle : Shape
{
    public Triangle() { m_var = new TriangleExtra(); }

    public void TriangleFunc()
    {
        m_var.TriangleExtraFunc();
    }
}
.
.
.



//Base_Class 2
class ShapeExtra
{
    public ShapeExtra() {}
}

class CircleExtra : ExtraClass
{
    public CircleExtra() {}
    void CircleExtraFunc() {//Do stuff}
}
class TriangleExtra : ExtraClass
{
    public TriangleExtra() {}
    void TriangleExtra() {//Do stuff}
}
.
.
.
```

So, I need the `m_var` in the child classes to be kept it as its own unique version. Because right now (w/o the extra `CircleExtra m_var;`), the `GetVar()` works, but in `CircleFunc`, `m_var` is still type of `ShapeExtra`, and thus **doesn't know that `CircleExtraFunc` exists**. I could cast `m_var` each time I wanted to do that, but that is repetitive and not worth it in my real-world case. Is there a way to utilize the functions in unique classes based off of `ShapeExtra`, while keeping the `GetVar()` function in `Shape`?

Please ask questions if there is anything I left out.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Added, "Is there a way to do this without casting each time?"

Comment: " I need the m_var in the child classes to be kept it as its own unique version." It already is. `m_var` in child classes has absolutely nothing to do with `m_var` in the base class. The base class has its own `m_var`, so does each child class. They are unique, and distinct. Unlike virtual functions, class members do not "override" members of the same name in the base class. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @RawN Is that better?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Tried adding them as possible solution, removed to better fit the situation. RawN, updated, shouldn't be a duplicate

Comment: Also, the header question doesn't fit very well, suggestions for changing it would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply with inheritance and without using pointers it is not possible, as C++ is a statically-and-strictly-typed language.

You can inherit both the variable and the function, but you'll need to cast function return value.

You can also override the function to make it return the concrete type, but then you have to cast the variable inside the function.

You can also declare the same var with the concrete class in subclasses, but then you just hide the variable in the superclass and inherit nothing.

I'd rather go for a solution using templates. Make the type of the variable a template type and extend the template using a concrete type in subclasses. It'll work perfectly.

It's been a long time since I last programmed in C++ and I beg your pardon if there are errors in the following example. I'm sure you can easily make it work.

```
template <class S>
class Shape {
   S m_var;
   //......
public:
   S var () {
      return m_var;
   }
   //.......
}

class Circle: Shape <CircleExtra> {
   // var method returns CircleExtra
   //......
}
```

Edit:
Regarding some comment, to allow virtual invocation of the method, it is possible to use correlated return types. Something like the following example.

```
class Shape {
public:
   virtual ShapeExtra *var () = 0;
}

template <typename SE>
class ConcreteShape: Shape {
public:
   virtual SE *var() {
      return &m_var;
   }
// Constructor, etc.

private:
   SE m_var;
}
```

Or some variation. Now concrete shapes can benefit from extending the template, as long as SE * is correlated with ShapeExtra * (the type parameter extends ShapeExtra). And you can vall the method transparently through Shape interface.

Comment: This approach does not allow scenarios where `Shape` is needed to be manipulated as the base class.

Comment: I think this is probably the best solution to my problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @KirillKobelev `Shape` is kinda an interface in my scenario, and won't ever be its own instance. I didn't completely specify that, sorry.

Comment: @KirillKobelev I add a suggestion to fulfill the need of virtual invocation through Shape class.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers, this is totally possible. 
Using your example, you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

//Extras
class ShapeExtra
{
    public:
    ShapeExtra() {}
    void ShapeFunc() { std::cout << "Shape"; }
    virtual ~ShapeExtra() = default; //Important!
};

class Shape
{
    public:
    std::unique_ptr<ShapeExtra> m_var;

    //require a pointer on construction
    //make sure to document, that Shape class takes ownership and handles deletion
    Shape(ShapeExtra* p):m_var(p){}

    //The common functions
    ShapeExtra& GetVar(){ return *m_var; }
    void ShapeFunc() {m_var->ShapeFunc();}
};


class CircleExtra : public ShapeExtra
{
    public:
    void CircleExtraFunc() {std::cout << "Circle";}
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
    CircleExtra* m_var;

    public:
    Circle() : Shape(new CircleExtra()) {
        m_var = static_cast<CircleExtra*>(Shape::m_var.get()); 
    }

    void CircleFunc()
    {
        m_var->CircleExtraFunc();
    }
};


int main() {
    Circle c;
    //use the ShapeExtra Object
    c.GetVar().ShapeFunc();
    //call via forwarded function
    c.ShapeFunc();
    //call the circleExtra Function
    c.CircleFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

[Test it on ideone](http://ideone.com/BW6era)

Note the use of pointers and a virtual destructor:

- By using a virtual destructor in the `ShapeExtra` base class, you make it possible to destruct an object of any derived class, using a `ShapeExtra*`. This is important, because
- by using a `std::unique_ptr<ShapeExtra>` instead of a plain C-pointer, we make sure that the object is properly deleted on destruction of `Shape`.
- It is probably a good idea to document this behaviour, i.e. that `Shape` takes the ownership of the `ShapeExtra*`. Which especially means, that we **do not delete `CirleExtra*` in the `Circle` destructor**
- I decided here to require the `ShapeExtra*` on construction, but its also possible to just use `std::unique_ptr::reset()` later and check for `nullptr` on dereferencing `Shape::m_var`
- Construction order is this: On calling the constructor of `Circle`, we first create a new `CircleExtra` which we pass to `Shape` before finally the constructor of `Circle` is executed.
- Destruction order is `Circle` first (was created last), then `Shape` which also destructs the `ShapeExtra` for us, including (via virtual function) the `CircleExtra`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following approach:

```
class ShapeExtra
{
public:

    virtual ~ShapeExtra() { }
    virtual void SomeCommonShapeFunc() { std::cout << "Shape"; }
};

class Shape
{
public:

    virtual ShapeExtra &GetVar() = 0; // Accessor function.
};
```

Note that the class `Shape` does not have any data members at all. After that for each derived class you need:

```
class CircleExtra : public ShapeExtra
{
public:

    void SomeCommonShapeFunc() { std::cout << "Circle"; }
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
    CircleExtra m_var;   // Data member with circle specific class.

public:

    virtual ShapeExtra &GetVar() { return m_var; }
};
```

Implementation of virtual method in `Circle` will return reference to the base class `ShapeExtra`. This will allow using this extra in the base class.

Note that pointers and templates are not used at all. This simplifies the overall design.